# How to get a value within a dictionary within a dictionary with just a string?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I'm trying to create a function that takes in a dictionary and a string and outputs a value within the Dictionary depending on the string.

For example, inputs would be:

```
D = {'assigned':{'id':4,'name':'myname'},'anotherkey':{'id':4,'name':'myname'}}
s = "['assigned']['id']"
```

Result:

```
4
```

This can also be achieved with the following, but the issue is that the function will only take a dictionary and a string

```
print D['assigned']['id']
>> 4
```

Comment: Does the input format have to be like that? It would be much simpler if the input is something like `'assigned-id'` or not a string, but a tuple of indexes like `('assigned', 'id')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use `eval()`, you can of course parse out the fields of the string yourself, using regular expressions for instance:

```
import re

def lookup(d, s):
  mo = re.match(r"\['([a-z]+)'\]\['([a-z]+)'\]", s)
  if mo and len(mo.groups()) == 2:
    return d[mo.group(1)][mo.group(2)]
  return None
```

You can do simpler parsing too since the input is pretty fixed.

Comment: +1, but `return None` is implicit in python, so no need for that.

Comment: It doesn't hurt to type it anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`, but you have to be sure that the string does contain things you want:

```
>>> eval("D"+s)
4
```

Answer (score 0):

`eval` can do this

```
>>> D = {'assigned':{'id':4,'name':'myname'},'anotherkey':{'id':4,'name':'myname'}}
>>> s = "['assigned']['id']"
>>> eval("D" +s)
4
```